# Liquibase 'includeAll' tag generates 2 rows in the databasechangelog table for the same changeset

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-migration, liquibase

I am using Liquibase version 4.0.0 to deploy DB migration scripts in PostgreSQL.

I use a master changelog file and it looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

<includeAll  path="4.460.7" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

My project structure looks like the following.

[image]

I use a `docker` container to run `liquibase update` in my Jenkinsfile as the following.

```
docker run --rm -v /home/jenkins/workspace/mate_DB_Migration_Scripts_master:/liquibase/changelog liquibase/liquibase --url="jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/postgres?currentSchema=schema1" --changeLogFile=../liquibase/changelog/changelog.xml --username=postgres --password=some_password update
docker run --rm -v /home/jenkins/workspace/mate_DB_Migration_Scripts_master:/liquibase/changelog liquibase/liquibase --url="jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/postgres?currentSchema=schema2" --changeLogFile=../liquibase/changelog/changelog.xml --username=postgres --password=some_password update
```

It runs the `update` just fine. The issue is I can see 2 rows in the `databasechangelog` file as the following for the same `changeset`.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? Please let me know if you want any other information to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an issue with the Liquibase Docker image.
More specifically with the combination of v4.0.0 and the "includeAll" tag.

As a workaround you can try the "include" tag instead, but you will have to include every single file.
like this:

```xml
<include file="path/to/<filename>.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

You can also try the sqlFile tag like this:

```xml
  <changeSet author="SteveZ" id="external-sql+rollback-script-example" context="QA" labels="Jira1000">
      <sqlFile dbms="mysql" splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="//" stripComments="true" path="objects/function/myFunction.sql"/>
      <rollback>
        <sqlFile dbms="mysql" splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="//" stripComments="true" path="objects/function/myFunction_rollback.sql"/>
      </rollback>
  </changeSet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @TsviZan for this answer. Actually, I tried this and it worked. And Liquibase support let me know that this is a known issue with the Liquibase Docker image. They are in the process of updating the bug it seems.